# CanCan Nested Resource Controller Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In my application, a user is allowed to assign another user as their "account manager" and the account manager would be allowed to modify all user info. I defined the following ability:

```
can :manage, User do |user|
    user == current_user or user.account_manager == current_user
end
```

A user also has some nested resources (e.g: publications). I defined the following ability:

```
can :manage, Publication do |publication, user|
    publication.user == current_user or user == current_user or user.account_manager == current_user
end
```

In the views I check using the following:
`can? :update, @publication, @user_we_are_accessing`
`can? :create, Publication.new, @user_we_are_accessing`.

Everything works just fine so far. My problem is with the controller. In my PublicationsController I added:
`load_and_authorize_resource :user`
`load_and_authorize_resource :publication, :through => :user`

However this **always** throws AccessDenied, because the check for publication is not passing the user object to the ability (trying to inspect the user object in the ability shows nil).

Any ideas how I can go about implementing this?

tl;dr: Using CanCan to authorize access to resources. User can assign another user as account manager. User has nested resources. Problem: nested resource is not accessible by account manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

1) replaced `load_and_authorize_resource :publication` with just loading the resource `load_resource :publication`
2) Added a `before_filter :authorize` after the load_resource call with the following implementaiton:

```
def authorize
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless can? :manage, @publication, @user
end
```

This works, but I was hoping for a way that would solve this in the devise way, if there is such a thing. Thoughts and feedback are appreciated.